# How to make Main VC's Toolbar global for all view controller

Tags: iphone

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
 UIView *baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

 [self.view addSubview:baseView];
 // Displays UIImageView
 UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc]
                 initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ka1_046.png"]];
 myImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
 [baseView addSubview:myImage]; 
 // create the UIToolbar at the bottom of the view controller
 toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 425, 320, 40)];
 toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
 [baseView addSubview:toolbar];
```

How can i make Main VC's UIToolbar which has no navigation controller and no tabbarcontroller global for all VC's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways,

First: you could instead of presenting the new viewcontrollers, you could just add them to the `self.view` and minimize their size to fit the view controller minus the tabbar

Second: you could share the instance of the tab bar in some global class, such as app delegate, just create the tab bar in the app delegate and add a property around it, so that other VC can access it, and then at each `viewDidLoad` of a new VC you would add it